# Check if time is expired in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if date is today, then user should not be able to pick expired time. However, if the date selected is tomorrow, then any time can be selected.

I am trying to do a check in jquery, but not sure how to check. Below is the code used:

```
var targetTime = new Date().setMinutes(-5).valueOf();
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd
    }

    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm
    }

    today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
    alert(today);
    if (jQuery('#startDatepicker').find("input").val() == today) {
        alert("Yes");
        var currentTime = jQuery('#startTimepicker').find("input").val();
        alert(currentTime);
        alert(targetTime);
        if (currentTime <= targetTime) {
            //Time Expired
            alert("HI");
        }
    }
```

The date is in the format of "MM/DD/YYYY", and the time is in format of "hh:mm a". Expired time of 5 minutes is allowed. How to validate the expired time using jQuery?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use same `Date` object you have:

```
// .valueOf() gives time in milliseconds 
var currentTime = new Date('25/12/2016 01:52').valueOf();
var targetTime = new Date().setMinutes(-5).valueOf();

if (currentTime <= targetTime) {
   // expired
} else {
   // not expired
}
```

Comment: Hi @Justinas.. I have updated my code, but it is not working. I am getting the alert yes, but the alert "Hi" is not shown

Comment: @venkat14 What does `console.log(currentTime + ' - '+targetTime)` returns?

Comment: @venkat14 Oh, you are using `currentTime` directly from input. You must pass this value to `currentTime = new Date($('#startTimepicker input').val())`

Comment: Hi @Justinas. I have different controls for date and time. startdatepicker has only the date in MM/DD/YYYY format. The field starttimepicker has time in "hh:mm a" format

Comment: Is it like this var newstime = jQuery('#startDatepicker').find("input").val() + currentTime; Also target time alert shows as 1486122939483

Comment: Any help on this?